# In second function x2() why return var pp only in second function?

Tags: javascript, closures

Can someone explain to me why the second function `x2()` needs to be returned second function `f()` to return our variable `pp`? Why not working only return `pp` after declare it?

```js
var pp = 10;

function x() {
  var pp = 20;
  return new Function('return pp;');
}

function x2() {
  var pp = 20;
  return function f() {
    return pp;
  }
  return f;
}

var p1 = x();
var p2 = x2();
console.log(p1());
console.log(p2());
```

Comment: One interesting thing is the `new Function('return pp;')` is not forming a closure and pointing to the global `pp` variable and printing 10.

Comment: What you say is also possible, but then you should `console.log(p2)` and not `console.log(p2())`. We cannot know what the aim is of the functions unless you tell us.

Comment: Of course you can just `return pp;` or even `return 20;`. It completely depends on what you expect the function to return (a function or a primitive value).

Comment: what I want is for example console.log(o) where o is global variable which have data from x2() pp

Comment: How would that `o` look like? Something like `o = {  data: 20 }` ? I don't understand the expected output...

Comment: var o = x2.pp;
console.log(o);

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario `x2` returns a function that holds value for the `pp` instead of the result of the function. `x2` is an example of closures in fact, you can read more about them here [Javascript Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

If you actually want to return the result from the initial call of `x2`, make this change:

```
function x2() {
  var pp = 20;
  function f() {
    return pp;
  }
  return f();
}
```

Comment: In that case, why not `return pp;` or `return 20;` for that matter?

Comment: well I think this example is about the understanding of the concept. But if it's actual code to use somewhere @trincot I 100% agree :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the function f, try leaving it at its own: for example,

```js
function x2() {
        var pp = 20;
        return function () {
            return pp;
        }
    }
console.log(x2())
console.log(x2()())
```

This allows x2()() to work, if that is what you are aiming for.

Comment: Yes that's ok for me but just if can someone explain how this works and why I need return function which returning my var and not only return var. ?

Comment: The reason why this works is because when you did it last time, you added a name: return function -->f<--, you dont put a name when returning a function. When this happens, you no longer need to return the function. Also, when you did it last time, it almost "self-ran" it.